# arrange GUI into multiple forms

Tags: c#, forms, user-interface

I developed a c# application with single(only one) Form.

Now I want to divide that GUI into multiple forms. If I cut and paste Textboxes and buttons into other forms we have to change the code to link all items again to work code properly.

Is there any easy way to do that without changing and modifying the code? 
(something like drag and drop without changing the code structure?)

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to drag the drop the controls but events and code you need to do it mannually.

Answer (score 0):

Try refactoring your form with user controls. Group all similar parts of GUI into one user control and then just include it as a control in your main form.

For example - if your form contains grid with different functions supported (sorting, filtering, editing,....) you might want to refactor that into a user control.

Unfortunately there is no easy way to do this but this will be a good excersise for you for the next time.